# How to launch browser after Docker start up in IntelliJ

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, browser

Is there a way to launch my web browser with localhost after I deploy a docker container?

In the Tomcat configurations, there is an `open browser after launch option`. How can I achieve this with Docker in IntelliJ?

Comment: This feature [was removed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171370) at some point. Feel free to [submit a new request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the use case if you need it.